# Iterating jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am attempting to iterate and output the values of the **choices** property using jquery **each(**). My code seems to output the array index and not the string values. why is this? Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/bkgzoq22/1/)

```
  var allQuestions = [
  {
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0
  }];


 $(info[0].choices).each(function(value){
    $('#answers').append($('<li>').text(value));
});
```

Comment: The first parameter of the callback is the `index`, you should use the second parameter.

Comment: the arguments given to each() callbacks is messed up. you want the 2nd argument for the value, don't ask me why the arity is like that.

Comment: If you are working with an unfamiliar method, I recommend to [read the **documentation** first](http://api.jquery.com/each/). *"why is this?"* Because that's how the method works.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused

```
$(selector).each()
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

with

```
$.each(array, callback)
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

You want to use the second form for iterating over arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the index instead of the value:

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0
}];


$(info[0].choices).each(function(index, value){
    $('#answers').append($('<li>').text(value));
});
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/436Lcvc4/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $(info[0].choices).each(function(value){
    $('#answers').append($('<li>').text(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.each` callback takes two arguments `index` and `value`. Add `value` as the second argument and use that argument instead.